# Update database from gridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have the following form on a winform project, i have a datagridview inside and i have an update button which i want by pushing it to update the corresponding table from the datagridview changes. The label tells me that the record updated successfully but when i query the database it doesnt work. Any ideas please? :

```
              private SqlConnection con;
    private SqlCommandBuilder scbCust;
    private SqlCommandBuilder scbOrd;
    private DataSet dsCommon;
    private SqlDataAdapter custAdapter;
      private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EbosPr.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);

        // Creating bridge between Server and DataSet
        custAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.CustCalls", con);


        // SqlCommandBuilder that can create Update commands
        scbCust = new SqlCommandBuilder(custAdapter);
        con.Open();

        // Filling dataset by respective adapter
        dsCommon = new DataSet();
        custAdapter.Fill(dsCommon, "CustCalls");


        // Set datagridview datasource
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsCommon.Tables["CustCalls"];

       con.Close();            
       }
   private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                con.Open();
        dsCommon.AcceptChanges();
        this.custAdapter.UpdateCommand = this.scbCust.GetUpdateCommand(true);
        int rowCust = this.custAdapter.Update(dsCommon.Tables["CustCalls"]);


        if (rowCust > 0)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "INFO: Record updated successfully!";
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

This is my connection string in app.config

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

Answer (score 1):

I really can't remember for sure, but I think it might be because you're calling AcceptChanges before your update.  You're telling your DataSet to accept all your edits and changes, which results in your updated rows having a RowState of Unchanged.  Then you do your Update, but it's saying, "Hey, these data rows are unchanged, so no updates needed!"

At least, I think that's how I remember this working.

This is untested, but I think this works?

```
DataSet dataSet;
SqlDataAdapter adapter;
string connectionString = "my connection string";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    dataSet = new DataSet();
    connection.Open();

    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable", connection);
    var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

    adapter.Fill(dataSet, "MyTable");

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["MyTable"];
}

//Whenever you update
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    if (adapter.Update(dataSet.Tables["MyTable"]) > 0)
        lblMessage.Text = "INFO: Record updated successfully!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would add a comment, but my rep's not high enough for that. Anyway, if you step through and debug, are the updates showing in the dataset prior to calling the update? I'm wondering if the changes made within the datagridview aren't being reflected in the dataset before the update is called. And the update statement may just be running an update on all rows. When stepping through, what is the value of rowCust when you click update?